# Why caching HTML5 page prevent doing Cors request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-appcache

Why caching an application prevent Cors request?

I have an example, two html page exactly Identical except the second line :

**index.html** [link](http://www.olivettom.com/test/index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html manifest="main.appcache">
```

**index2.html** [link](http://www.olivettom.com/test/index2.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Why the one **without** manifest is working fine and the one with manifest **works only the first time** and stop working when the application is cached? (press F5 several times)

I tested with Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: And if you save on your desktop ... it works!

Comment: What does CORS have to do with this, are you actually doing any cross-domain calls ?

Comment: Did you try to update your appcache with NETWORK section, which allows requests? Try with simple NETWORK *. Details here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/. Otherwise if your FastFlicker is not under CACHE section, it won't be loaded, and cache returns 404, which means that resource isnt cached

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/)

> NETWORK:
>   Files listed in this section may come from the network if they aren't in the cache, otherwise the network isn't used, even if the user is online. You can white-list specific URLs here, or simply "*", which allows all URLs. Most sites need "*".

So behaviour you've described is appropriate, because your appcache manifest doesn't contain NETWORK section.

*Update*: request that fails - isn't CORS - because domain, protocol and port are the same.